# USB installation

Tags: boot, usb, system-installation, wubi, sony

I am trying to install/live run Ubuntu 12.04.4 on Sony Vaio TGZ laptop.  I've downloaded the ISO from the Ubntu website.  Formatted a 16gbit USB drive as 32bit FAT. I've downloaded the UUI and run it to install the OS on the USB drive.  I run the WUBI.exe which gives me 3 options: reboot now, reboot later and help with boot from CD.  Click on any of these and then click finish and then nothing.  I have set the laptop to boot from USB first.  Help, please.

Comment: Use UNetBootin to create the Bootstick. And don't use WUBI. It's instable.

Comment: where do want to install the Ubuntu OS, USB or Hard Drive?